# Load ImageFile from DLL

Tags: c#, dll, windows-phone-8, resources

I build a modular application with a WindowsPhone 8 Project and a WP8 DLL. I try to reference a image in the DLL in code behind of the WP8 Project.

I tried

```
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/DllAssemblyName;component/Assets/image.png",
    UriKind.Absolute));
```

Here I get a `Invalid URI: Invalid port specified.`

I also tried

```
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/DllAssemblyName;component/Assets/image.png",
    UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

This work's with out exceptions but the image is not visible.

What do I wrong?

Comment: What build action have you assigned the image in the DLL?

Comment: I tried Content, Ressource and Embbeded Ressource, Also Copy never and Copy allways